# real full shell for windows

Tags: windows, shell, console

I need a command console for Windows (other than powersell), to replace cmd.exe fully capable of running batch scripts and do the same is done with cmd.exe, but (very important) that has no dependence cmd.exe.
I've seen some as cmder, PyCmd, and are a pretty cmd.exe, not a shell.

Comment: You probably want a Linux system.

Comment: yes, you all right. Linux is the best, but this is not the answer to my cuestion. sorry

Comment: Off-topic here, you might try Super User.  But you'll also need to provide more information, it isn't clear what your requirements are from what you've written so far.  It almost sounds as if you just want a third-party clone of cmd.exe, but that seems pretty pointless.  There must be some specific feature(s) you're looking for that cmd.exe doesn't provide, what are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Mingw, it comes with a collection of GNU utilities which might help you out. Anyway, in the future your problem will most certainly disappear because ubuntu is coming to windows [Ubuntu on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about).

You can download it here [Mingw](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys), in my case I have it installed because of GIT package. After the installation process you will have access to a command line with multiple features available on linux.